# Using Shiny inputs in lm()

Tags: r, input, shiny, lm

I have the following shiny input panel:

```
inputPanel(selectInput(inputId = "engagement_state", label = "Choose Engagement State:",
                   choices = states.of.engagement2, selected = states.of.engagement2[1]), 
       selectInput(inputId = "product", label = "Choose a Product:",
                   choices = unique.products, selected = unique.products[1]),
       selectInput(inputId = "model_inputs", label = "Choose Input Variables:",
                   choices = model.variables, selected = model.variables, multiple = TRUE))
```

Using these inputs, I want to create a model. The dependent variable is input$engagement_state and the independent variables are the variables included input$model_inputs as well as another column that is added into the data shown below

```
renderDataTable({
  aggregated.engagement <- data[get(variable.product) != input$product, .(agg_engagement = mean(get(input$engagement_state), na.rm=T)), by=id][, agg_engagement := ifelse(agg_engagement == "NaN", 0, agg_engagement)]
  
  model.data <- merge(data[get(variable.product) == input$product], aggregated.engagement, by='id')
  inputs <- c(input$model_inputs, variable.product, "agg_engagement")
  model.formula <- as.formula(paste0(input$engagement_state, "~", paste0(inputs, collapse = "+")))
  
  if (input$engagement_state == variable.satisfaction) {
    model <- lm(model.formula, model.data)

    ci <- data.frame(cbind(Estimate = coef(model), confint(model, level = 0.95)))
    displaytable <- rownames_to_columns(ci, "Coefficient")
    pvalues <- rownames_to_column(data.frame(coef(summary(model))[,4]), "Coefficient")
    displaytable <- merge(displaytable, pvalues, by='Coefficient') %>%
      rename("5% CI" = "X2.5..", "95% CI" = "X97.5..", "P-Value" = "coef.summary.model.....4.")

    datatable(displaytable)
  }
  
  if (input$engagement_state != variable.satisfaction) {
    model <- glm(model.formula, family = 'binomial', model.data)

    or <- data.frame(exp(cbind(OR = coef(model), confint(model, level=0.95))))
    displaytable <- rownames_to_column(or, "Coefficient")
    pvalues <- rownames_to_column(data.frame(coef(summary(model))[,4]), "Coefficient")
    displaytable <- merge(displaytable, pvalues, by='Coefficient') %>%
      rename("Odds Ratio" = "OR", "5% CI" = "X2.5..", "95% CI" = "X97.5..", "P-Value" = "coef.summary.model.....4.")

    datatable(displaytable)
  }
})
```

aggregated.engagement is based on the product that is selected in the inputs, and I then aggregated that variable with the rest of the inputs. Of the engagement state inputs, all are binary but one is on a scale from 0-10 (satisfaction) so for satisfaction there should be a linear model and for the rest of the states it should be a logit model.

After the model is created, I create a table including coefficients or odds ratios, confidence intervals and p-values and that's what should be output

Here's reproducible data:

```
dput(data[1:100,])
structure(list(id = 1:100, Age = c(57L, 67L, 55L, 58L, 70L, 58L, 
47L, 64L, 53L, 58L, 65L, 39L, 57L, 26L, 66L, 38L, 27L, 46L, 64L, 
44L, 66L, 24L, 35L, 32L, 44L, 56L, 71L, 35L, 25L, 57L, 61L, 32L, 
19L, 39L, 51L, 32L, 45L, 44L, 67L, 64L, 72L, 50L, 70L, 38L, 48L, 
49L, 46L, 65L, 72L, 61L, 19L, 43L, 42L, 39L, 52L, 25L, 51L, 68L, 
44L, 53L, 61L, 43L, 47L, 37L, 41L, 30L, 51L, 52L, 29L, 26L, 22L, 
25L, 68L, 55L, 50L, 64L, 50L, 53L, 20L, 59L, 37L, 35L, 54L, 41L, 
58L, 55L, 69L, 62L, 48L, 43L, 61L, 43L, 64L, 31L, 61L, 51L, 29L, 
60L, 59L, 48L), Gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor"), Income = c(85000, 38000, 77000, 47000, 
76000, 128000, 163000, 91000, 54000, 78000, 36000, 119000, 164000, 
16000, 109000, 109000, 109000, 158000, 118000, 36000, 36000, 
43000, 51000, 166000, 98000, 39000, 117000, 45000, 50000, 82000, 
46000, 76000, 122000, 76000, 87000, 42000, 46000, 35000, 72000, 
44000, 29000, 58000, 38000, 49000, 107000, 36000, 80000, 89000, 
28000, 121000, 35000, 112000, 123000, 31000, 47000, 152000, 87000, 
42000, 76000, 35000, 33000, 47000, 145000, 91000, 120000, 32000, 
41000, 78000, 52000, 32000, 58000, 129000, 174000, 73000, 36000, 
65000, 51000, 130000, 49000, 171000, 93000, 61000, 46000, 166000, 
82000, 23000, 169000, 46000, 163000, 78000, 127000, 43000, 164000, 
135000, 126000, 162000, 90000, 57000, 38000, 79000), Region = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L), levels = c("Midwest", "Northeast", "South", "West"
), class = "factor"), Persona = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 
6L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 
4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Ambivalent Adventurer", 
"Consistent Compromiser", "Materialistic Meditator", "Outdoorsy Ombudsman", 
"Precociously Preoccupied", "Technological Triumphalist"), class = "factor"), 
    Product = structure(c(18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), levels = c("All Buttons", 
    "App Map", "Buzzdial", "Cellularity", "Communic Nation", 
    "Maybe Mobile", "Mobile Mayhem", "MobilitEE", "Mobzilla", 
    "Next Text", "No Buttons", "Off the Hook", "Phonatics", "Phone Zone", 
    "Pocket Dialz", "Ring Ring", "Screenz", "Smartophonic", "Speed Dials", 
    "Triumphone"), class = "factor"), Awareness = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), BP_User_Friendly_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5L, 8L, 5L, NA, 9L, 8L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 7L, NA, 7L, NA, NA, 7L, 9L, 
    NA, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 6L, 4L, NA, 7L, 1L, 7L, 8L, NA, 
    6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 
    5L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, NA, 8L, NA, 5L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 
    7L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, NA, 1L, 5L, 9L, NA, 5L, 
    6L, NA, NA, NA, 7L, NA, NA, 5L, 9L), BP_Fast_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 6L, 10L, 7L, NA, 8L, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, 
    8L, 6L, 6L, NA, 9L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 7L, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 10L, 
    10L, NA, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 3L, 9L, NA, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
    8L, NA, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 6L, NA, 
    4L, NA, 2L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, 4L, 
    7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, NA, NA, 7L, NA, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 4L, 7L, 
    5L, NA, 7L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 7L, NA, NA, 6L, 7L), BP_Battery_Life_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 7L, 6L, 7L, NA, 5L, 9L, NA, 8L, NA, NA, 6L, 8L, 
    9L, 9L, NA, 8L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 7L, NA, 7L, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 
    NA, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 6L, 9L, NA, 1L, 5L, 5L, 7L, NA, 
    6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 7L, NA, 5L, NA, 8L, 
    8L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, NA, 8L, NA, 5L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 
    4L, NA, NA, 10L, NA, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, NA, 8L, 9L, 5L, NA, 
    6L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, NA, NA, 4L, 7L), BP_Camera_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5L, 6L, 8L, NA, 10L, 7L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 6L, 
    7L, 9L, 5L, NA, 8L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 7L, NA, 8L, NA, NA, 8L, 
    3L, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 7L, 6L, NA, 8L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 
    NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 6L, NA, 7L, NA, 
    7L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 7L, 5L, 9L, NA, 8L, NA, 7L, 6L, 9L, 
    9L, 8L, NA, NA, 7L, NA, 4L, 8L, 6L, 4L, NA, 8L, 7L, 7L, NA, 
    5L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 6L, 5L), BP_Sleek_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 8L, 6L, 4L, NA, 6L, 9L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 3L, 6L, 
    10L, 8L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 6L, NA, 8L, NA, NA, 6L, 
    8L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 6L, 6L, NA, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
    NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 7L, NA, 6L, NA, 
    6L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 8L, 5L, 2L, NA, 10L, NA, 7L, 3L, 
    7L, 5L, 6L, NA, NA, 8L, NA, 5L, 9L, 6L, 9L, NA, 4L, 8L, 6L, 
    NA, 4L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, NA, NA, 7L, 10L), BP_Stylish_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 8L, 5L, 8L, NA, 3L, 6L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 7L, NA, 8L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 6L, NA, 7L, NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 
    NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 10L, 9L, NA, 7L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 
    NA, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 8L, NA, 4L, NA, 
    8L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, 9L, 7L, 
    7L, 10L, NA, NA, 9L, NA, 8L, 9L, 7L, 6L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    NA, 9L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 6L, 6L), BP_Status_Symbol_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 8L, 10L, 10L, NA, 7L, 9L, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 3L, 
    4L, 8L, 5L, NA, 10L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 9L, NA, 9L, NA, NA, 
    6L, 7L, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 6L, 10L, NA, 5L, 7L, 
    6L, 6L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 5L, NA, 
    9L, NA, 7L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 6L, 9L, 9L, NA, 7L, NA, 8L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 7L, 5L, 3L, 4L, NA, 6L, 8L, 
    7L, NA, 8L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 8L, 4L), BP_Good_Screen_Size_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4L, 7L, 8L, NA, 3L, 7L, NA, 9L, NA, NA, 5L, 7L, 
    8L, 5L, NA, 7L, NA, NA, NA, 9L, 6L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 8L, 6L, 
    NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 4L, 6L, NA, 9L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 
    NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 8L, NA, 10L, 
    NA, 9L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 2L, 2L, 10L, NA, 8L, NA, 4L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, NA, NA, 9L, NA, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, NA, 9L, 
    7L, 4L, NA, 5L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 5L, 8L), BP_Boring_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 3L, 7L, 3L, NA, 6L, 3L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 4L, 2L, 
    7L, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 
    NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 7L, 6L, NA, 5L, 2L, 4L, 0L, NA, 
    5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 
    5L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, NA, 6L, NA, 4L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, NA, NA, 10L, NA, 9L, 5L, 8L, 2L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 
    8L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 6L, 5L), BP_Bulky_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 1L, NA, 6L, 5L, NA, 7L, NA, NA, 6L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, NA, 7L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 
    NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 7L, 7L, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, NA, 
    6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 4L, 4L, NA, 6L, NA, 
    5L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 6L, 8L, 3L, NA, 6L, NA, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 3L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, 2L, 7L, 2L, NA, 4L, 6L, 5L, NA, 
    3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 5L, 6L), BP_Fragile_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5L, 3L, 3L, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 
    3L, 8L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 6L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, 0L, 
    NA, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 7L, 7L, NA, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, NA, 
    9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 2L, NA, 6L, NA, 0L, 
    4L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 4L, 3L, 7L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 
    5L, NA, NA, 6L, NA, 4L, 4L, 6L, 7L, NA, 8L, 4L, 0L, NA, 4L, 
    4L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 3L, 6L), BP_Expensive_0_10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5L, 2L, 6L, NA, 7L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 6L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 5L, 3L, 
    NA, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 7L, 2L, NA, 6L, 2L, 8L, 6L, NA, 
    3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 1L, 
    5L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 8L, 5L, 4L, NA, 1L, NA, 6L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 
    4L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 5L, 10L, 8L, 6L, NA, 1L, 2L, 5L, NA, 
    3L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 7L, 6L), Consideration = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 
    NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, NA, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, 1L, 
    0L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), Consumption = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 0L, 1L, 
    NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), Satisfaction = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4L, 6L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 
    NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 
    4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 6L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 6L, 
    3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 4L), Advocacy = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0L, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 0L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), age_group = c("50-64", "65+", 
    "50-64", "50-64", "65+", "50-64", "34-49", "50-64", "50-64", 
    "50-64", "65+", "34-49", "50-64", "18-34", "65+", "34-49", 
    "18-34", "34-49", "50-64", "34-49", "65+", "18-34", "34-49", 
    "18-34", "34-49", "50-64", "65+", "34-49", "18-34", "50-64", 
    "50-64", "18-34", "18-34", "34-49", "50-64", "18-34", "34-49", 
    "34-49", "65+", "50-64", "65+", "50-64", "65+", "34-49", 
    "34-49", "34-49", "34-49", "65+", "65+", "50-64", "18-34", 
    "34-49", "34-49", "34-49", "50-64", "18-34", "50-64", "65+", 
    "34-49", "50-64", "50-64", "34-49", "34-49", "34-49", "34-49", 
    "18-34", "50-64", "50-64", "18-34", "18-34", "18-34", "18-34", 
    "65+", "50-64", "50-64", "50-64", "50-64", "50-64", "18-34", 
    "50-64", "34-49", "34-49", "50-64", "34-49", "50-64", "50-64", 
    "65+", "50-64", "34-49", "34-49", "50-64", "34-49", "50-64", 
    "18-34", "50-64", "50-64", "18-34", "50-64", "50-64", "34-49"
    ), income_group = c("75,000 - 99,999", "Under 50,000", "75,000 - 99,999", 
    "Under 50,000", "75,000 - 99,999", "100,000 - 149,999", "150,000 or Higher", 
    "75,000 - 99,999", "50,000 - 74,999", "75,000 - 99,999", 
    "Under 50,000", "100,000 - 149,999", "150,000 or Higher", 
    "Under 50,000", "100,000 - 149,999", "100,000 - 149,999", 
    "100,000 - 149,999", "150,000 or Higher", "100,000 - 149,999", 
    "Under 50,000", "Under 50,000", "Under 50,000", "50,000 - 74,999", 
    "150,000 or Higher", "75,000 - 99,999", "Under 50,000", "100,000 - 149,999", 
    "Under 50,000", "50,000 - 74,999", "75,000 - 99,999", "Under 50,000", 
    "75,000 - 99,999", "100,000 - 149,999", "75,000 - 99,999", 
    "75,000 - 99,999", "Under 50,000", "Under 50,000", "Under 50,000", 
    "50,000 - 74,999", "Under 50,000", "Under 50,000", "50,000 - 74,999", 
    "Under 50,000", "Under 50,000", "100,000 - 149,999", "Under 50,000", 
    "75,000 - 99,999", "75,000 - 99,999", "Under 50,000", "100,000 - 149,999", 
    "Under 50,000", "100,000 - 149,999", "100,000 - 149,999", 
    "Under 50,000", "Under 50,000", "150,000 or Higher", "75,000 - 99,999", 
    "Under 50,000", "75,000 - 99,999", "Under 50,000", "Under 50,000", 
    "Under 50,000", "100,000 - 149,999", "75,000 - 99,999", "100,000 - 149,999", 
    "Under 50,000", "Under 50,000", "75,000 - 99,999", "50,000 - 74,999", 
    "Under 50,000", "50,000 - 74,999", "100,000 - 149,999", "150,000 or Higher", 
    "50,000 - 74,999", "Under 50,000", "50,000 - 74,999", "50,000 - 74,999", 
    "100,000 - 149,999", "Under 50,000", "150,000 or Higher", 
    "75,000 - 99,999", "50,000 - 74,999", "Under 50,000", "150,000 or Higher", 
    "75,000 - 99,999", "Under 50,000", "150,000 or Higher", "Under 50,000", 
    "150,000 or Higher", "75,000 - 99,999", "100,000 - 149,999", 
    "Under 50,000", "150,000 or Higher", "100,000 - 149,999", 
    "100,000 - 149,999", "150,000 or Higher", "75,000 - 99,999", 
    "50,000 - 74,999", "Under 50,000", "75,000 - 99,999")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x14000a4e0>)
>
```

Comment: Hello amatof, i don't understand what kind of output want you render to the table, since `lm` does not return a dataframe.  Want to plot `predict(res)`?

Comment: @RicVillalba sorry, that last line can be ignored for now, once I create the model I will be putting together table outputs to create a table. For now, all I need to know is how to use the inputs to create the model

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure without your data, but I think the issue is that you need to make a formula object from your inputs. Here is an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "var.x1", 
              label = strong("X-Variable1"),
              choices = colnames(mtcars),
              selected = "cyl"),
  selectInput(inputId = "var.x2", 
              label = strong("X-Variable2"),
              choices = colnames(mtcars),
              selected = "hp"),
  selectInput(inputId = "var.y", 
              label = strong("y-Variable"),
              choices = colnames(mtcars),
              selected = "mpg"),
   verbatimTextOutput('lm')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$lm <- renderPrint(expr = {
    inputs <- paste(c(input$var.x1, input$var.x2), collapse = " + ")
    forms <- as.formula(paste0(input$var.y, "~",  inputs))
    model <- lm(forms, data = mtcars)
    return(summary(model))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think this is only using the column name not actually pulling the column if that makes sense, I'm getting the "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels" error

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code above runs on my local computer. Maybe your data has some other nuance, but without the data, I can't say for sure.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the full code as well as reproducible data

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly what you want is:

```
renderDataTable({
  aggregated.engagement <- data[get(variable.product) != input$product, .(agg_engagement = mean(get(input$engagement_state), na.rm=T)), by=id][, agg_engagement := ifelse(agg_engagement == "NaN", 0, agg_engagement)]
  
  model.data <- merge(data[get(variable.product) == input$product], aggregated.engagement, by='id')
  inputs <- c(input$model_inputs, input$product, "aggregated.engagement")
  model_formula <- as.formula( paste(input$engagement_state, "~", paste(inputs, collapse = "+")))
  model <- lm(model_formula,  model.data)
 
})
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels" and I have a feeling this is only pulling the character of the column name and not the actual column, I've updated the question with my full code and a subset of the data, would you be able to take a look?